Can a table which has larger record gets often hitting in for each loop cause performance issue? - PROGRESS 4GL
I have a below simple query which causes a performance issue. a table xxdata has huge records and it's getting often hits based on total records available in table xxfin.(i.e Available records 1000 in table xxfin, then 1000 times hits table xxdata).
This is causing performance issue. As checked XREF of this query, compiler shows correct indexes for both table.
FOR EACH xxfin NO-LOCK WHERE xxfin.setValue = 9:
**Some additional logic goes here but this is not causing any issues, Since I have commented them and checked**
    FOR EACH xxdata NO-LOCK 
       WHERE xxdata.linkno = xxfin.setValue
       AND xxdata.duo = "FINISHED":
    END. /*FOR EACH xxdata*/
END. /*FOR EACH xxfin */


When you say "causes a performance issue" it is helpful to know the specifics. How are you measuring this issue? What measurement would be acceptable? Additionally some numbers characterizing what you consider a "huge" record to be would be helpful. Lastly - what do you mean by "hits"? Do you mean the number of records returned by the query? Or are you referring to something like the PROMON "hit ratio" metric?

I note that you say that XREF shows that the code is using the "correct" indexes. None the less - it would be helpful to tell us what the components of those indexes are and their structure.

OpenEdge query efficiency and performance depend on the quality of the indexes selected and the amount of data being processed by the client.
In your example if xxfin.setValue is the leading component of an index then, because you have a simple "equality match", that part of the code block is selecting the minimum number of xxfin records.
However - if xxfin.setValue is NOT the leading component of an index you will be processing a "WHOLE-INDEX" table scan. IOW you will examine every record in the table to see if setValue = 9.
(You can compile your code with the XREF option and look for SEARCH in the output to see what index is being selected, even when an index is being used the phrase WHOLE-INDEX means that a table scan is taking place.)
Similarly if xxdata.linkno and xxdata.duo are leading components (in either order) then your second query should be quite efficient.
In your question you seem to be saying that the outer loop selects roughly 1000 records. So that loop is iterating 1000 times. And with each iteration the inner loop will run in its entirety. Even though it only cares about "xxdata.linkno = 9". So, yes, it is doing about 1000x more work than it needs to do. It is doing the same work over and over and over again. It might be efficiently doing that work, but it is still 1000x more work than it needs to be doing.
However - as shown, your outer loop appears to be unnecessary. It seems to me that you could rewrite this whole block of code as:
for each xxdata no-lock
  where xxdata.linkno = 9 
    and xxdata.duo = "finished":

  /* do stuff */

end.

Eliminating the outer loop would also (potentially) allow "messages" to be packed with more data (this is impacted by the -Mm, -prefetchNumRecs, and -prefetchFactor startup parameters; "bigger is better"). Packing more data into each message and avoiding needlessly splitting messages when the outer loop pointlessly iterates will help.
But the big improvement comes from not doing the same inner loop over and over for no reason.
If you are doing something that is not shown with the xxfin records you can still do that. Just refactor that to happen inside the xxdata loop. Perhaps like this:
for each xxdata no-lock
  where xxdata.linkno = 9 
    and xxdata.duo = "finished":

  find xxfin no-lock where xxfin.setvalue = xxdata.linkno.

  /* do stuff */

end.

Of course the logic will depend on what, if anything, you were doing (that you have not shown) in the outer loop but there is probably a way to move it inside.
Alternatively - maybe you meant to have the two loops execute independently? Something more like:
for each xxfin no-lock where xxfin.setValue = 9:
  /* logic that was not shown */
end.

for each xxdata no-lock
  where xxdata.linkno = 9 
    and xxdata.duo = "finished":

  /* do stuff */

end.

Another thing that you can do is to employ a FIELDS list if the connection type is a remote connection (you used -S in the client startup parameters).
For example:
for each xxdata fields( linkno duo )no-lock
  where xxdata.linkno = 9 
    and xxdata.duo = "finished":

  /* do stuff */

end.

Real code would need to list the fields that are actually referenced where the "do stuff" comment is.
This will reduce the size of the data transmitted which will result in better performance. In a remote connection scenario the improvement could be dramatic.
